# Why does $\mathrm{cis}\left(2\pi x\right)$ not equal $1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{cis}\left(\theta\right) &= \cos\left(\theta\right)+i\sin\left(\theta\right) \\
                                &= e^{i\theta}
\end{align}\\
$$$$
\text{Let } \theta = 2\pi x \\
$$$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{cis}\left(2\pi x\right) &= e^{i\times2\pi x} \\
                                &= \left(e^{2\pi i}\right)^x \\
                                &= 1^x \\
                                &= 1
\end{align}
$$

This is clearly not true for any $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$. Where is the error?

Is it because, when the value of $x$ is substituted back in, the equation becomes

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{cis}\left(\theta\right) &= 1^\frac{\theta}{2\pi} \\
                                &= \sqrt[2\pi]{1^\theta} \\
                                &= \sqrt[2\pi]{1} 
\end{align}
$$

which would have infinite solutions(?) since $2\pi$ is irrational?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(a^b)^c =a^{bc}$ is not always true for complex numbers.